# phpMyAdmin - blank page with no errors on Debian8, php7.0-fpm

Tags: nginx, debian, php-fpm, phpmyadmin

phpMyAdmin does not display the login page on my server:

- OS: Debian 8.6 Jessie
- PHP: php7.0-fpm
- Webserver: Nginx 1.10.1

When I look at source code, it contains login form but for some reason all browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera) instead of login form shows blank page.

**I have checked**

- nginx logfiles
- mysql logfiles
- php-fpm logfiles

but there are no errors

**Firefox console shows:**

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Saber más]get_scripts.js.php:1
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Saber más]get_scripts.js.php:1
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Saber más]get_scripts.js.php:1
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Saber más]get_scripts.js.php:1
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Saber más]messages.php:363:1
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Saber más]get_image.js.php:1
ReferenceError: PMA_commonParams is not defined
[Saber más]dgtrgdre545fgrt65hfgtr8ghda:2:1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by Cloudflare. The problem is already described [here](http://www.staze.org/phpmyadmin-not-working-cloudflare/). UNfortunately, the solution from this article does not work for me and phpMyAdmin still shows blank page.

Comment: It would be better to take the time to describe the solution than link to another page since links can and will brake and other people with the same question would have now chance of following.